# Swift replace associated type with concrete type in sub-protocol

Tags: swift, generics

```
protocol A {
    associatedtype T
    var t: T { get }
}

protocol B: A where T == Int {}

var b: B? = nil     //  Protocol 'B' can only be used as a generic constraint
                    //  because it has Self or associated type requirements.
```

Is there a way to create an extended protocol (B)
that assigns a concrete type to the base protocol's (A's)
associated type, and by doing so "removes" the associated type requirements,
and becomes a protocol with no associated types, usable not only as a generic constraint?

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't seem to work so the associated type always stays inside

```
protocol A {
    associatedtype T
    var t: T { get }
}

protocol B: A {
    override associatedtype T = Int
}
```

There are methods to overcome this, for example wrapped classes

```
 class WrappedB: B {
    var t: Int
    
    init<S: B>(_ object: S) where S.T == Int {
        self.t = object.t
    }
}

var b: WrappedB = WrappedB(BB())
```